# Using HTML, I wish to have a page look for a login, if yes, then continue on, otherwise ask for login

Tags: redirect, authentication, content-management-system

Basically, we have a certain area of the site we want only logged in members to see. If a non-member clicks a link to this area, it should challenge them for a login (that part I have down). If the person is already logged in, then the page would normally challenge for a login, it would instead redirect to the destination page.

The Problem I have with this is knowing where/how to grab the appropriate information to issue a redirect to forward already logged-in members. I have seen solutions, but they're mostly in PHP and I can't use that due to working in a CMS.....

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to check whether a person visiting the page is logged in or not. This could be done using sessions or cookies. Unless you specify which CMS you are using, it's difficult to give you a specific answer.